# Is there a faithful two-dimensional representation for the Bianchi IV Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

The Bianchi type IV Lie algebra (do they call it *L(3,3)?* ), 
$$
[y,z] = 0, \qquad      [x,y] = y,  \qquad       [x, z] = y + z , 
$$
has the evident adjoint representation by 3×3 matrices.

Would it further have a 2-dimensional rep, 2×2 
matrices—analogous to Pauli's for su(2)?

Comment: See [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjejc_nvYPnAhXNPFAKHaG6DwUQFjACegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp%2FEMIS%2Fjournals%2FBMMSS%2Fpdf%2Fv36n2%2Fv36n2p9.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3DaNkXJGD7CBS6jcz0bH1Y) with references to my papers :) The authors also have done this for dimension $3$. I think the nimmal dimesnion of a faithful representation is $3$.

Comment: The mistitled Mubarakzyanov ref [7] appears to cover this, but I haven't accessed a translation of the Russian, yet.

Comment: You can do this yourself easily. Write operators $f_x,f_y,f_z$ as $2\times 2$ matrices with these relations in unknowns and just compute. Then $f$ will not be faithful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Indeed, after conjugation, the image would be exactly the Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices, which is not isomorphic to yours since it has a nontrivial center.

Actually, over the complex numbers every Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ is isomorphic to $\{0\}$, $\mathfrak{a}$ the 1-dimensional abelian Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{b}$ (the 2-dim non-abelian Lie algebra), $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, or the direct product of one of these three by $\mathfrak{a}$.